# How to deploy to github releases from travis

Tags: github, travis-ci

I have some repository with a electron-js project. I'm trying to setup build and deploy to github releases from travis CI.

I have next config:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - "8"

before_install:
  - cd app

install:
  - npm install

os:
  - linux
  - osx

env:
  - TARGET_ARCH=x64

script:
  - npm run dist

branches:
  only:
    - master

deploy:
  provider: releases
  skip_cleanup: true
  api_key: $GH_TOKEN
```

Travis successfully builds app, but didn't upload artifacts to github releases.
As I understood the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/), It should create a new release with tag `untagged-*` and upload files to it.
Now I have this messages in build log:

> skipped publishing file=Cromberg_1.2.1_amd64.deb reason=existing type
>   not compatible with publishing type tag=v1.2.1 version=1.2.1
>   existingType=release publishingType=draft

`1.2.1` is a previous tag. What am I doing wrong?

I want to automatically build and creating releases with artifacts on every commit with tags in master branch. But now I just trying to setup deploy on any event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deploy to github releases on tags you should have a part of config like this:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  skip_cleanup: true
  api_key: $GH_TOKEN
  file_glob: true
  file:
    - "dist/Cromberg-*-x86_64.AppImage"
    - "dist/Cromberg_*_amd64.deb"
    - "dist/Cromberg-*.dmg"
  on:
    tags: true
```

Also don't set branches in config like this:

```
 branches:
  only:
  - master
```

Because it will build only on this branch and don't use tags (but in deploy config we set tags: true)

Thus, when you make a commit with some tag on master, it will build your app twice: first build on master branch, deploy step will be skipped. Another build on tag, it will create release during this build and upload files to release.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the **deploy** parameters correctly in travis.yml, look this:

```
language: go

go:
  - "1.10"

script:
  - CGO_ENABLED=0 go build
  - ls

deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key: $TOKEN
  file: "test"
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: false
```

If you set **tags: false**, then travis will release your app with **untagged tag** like this:

[image]

Comment: I thought, that tags: false is by default. 

Also in build log a saw `skipped publishing file=... reason=existing type not compatible with publishing type...`, that's why I thought that it isn't necessary to define files to upload, if you want it all.

Thanks